# QTableView how do I enter edit mode when I press enter or return button?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyqt5, pyside2

By default, you can set triggers to enter cell regactivation mode via the setEditTriggers function. However, there is no trigger for the enter or return button.

I tried to do this through overriding the keyPressEvent function. But it gives me a **"edit: editing failed"** error in the terminal.

```
class UTableView(QTableView):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(UTableView, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setEditTriggers(QAbstractItemView.DoubleClicked | QAbstractItemView.EditKeyPressed)

    def keyPressEvent(self, event):
        if event.type() == QEvent.KeyPress and (event.key() == Qt.Key_Return or event.key() == Qt.Key_Enter):
            self.edit(self.currentIndex())
        super(UTableView, self).keyPressEvent(event)
```

What is the right way to solve my problem?

Answer (score 2):

Found out what my problem was.
The solution given in the question is correct. But we need to add a check to see if the element is in a state of editing. Because when we press enter or return button after we changed text in a cell to make a change, keyPressEvent is also triggered and since the previous change is not finished yet, it gives error "edit: editing failed".

Final code:

```
class UTableView(QTableView):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(UTableView, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setEditTriggers(QAbstractItemView.DoubleClicked | QAbstractItemView.EditKeyPressed)

    def keyPressEvent(self, event):
        if event.type() == QEvent.KeyPress and (event.key() == Qt.Key_Return or event.key() == Qt.Key_Enter):
            if self.state() != QAbstractItemView.EditingState:
                self.edit(self.currentIndex())
        super(QTableView, self).keyPressEvent(event)
```